# how to print 5 unique strings from array of 10 strings

Tags: c, arrays, random, srand

I am writing a code which will print 5 unique and random strings from an array of 10 strings. But my code doesn't print it uniquely, there are always some repetitions.
Here is my code, can anyone suggest how to make it print unique?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>




void main(void){
    char arr[10][10]={"abc","def","ghi","klm","nop","qrs","tuv","wxy","zab","cde"};
    int i=0,j=0;

    srand(time(0));

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){

    j=rand()%10;
    printf("%d\n",j);

    }
}
```

Comment: You could keep a history of used numbers and check if the number drawn has already occurred in the history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remember idices that have already been printed out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[10][10] = {"abc","def","ghi","klm","nop","qrs","tuv","wxy","zab","cde"};
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int done[10] = { 0 };

    srand(time(0));

    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        do
        {
            j = rand()%10;
        }
        while (done[j] == 1);
        done[j] = 1;
        printf("%s\n", arr[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `rand()` function may evaluate to the same string index multiple times.  There are different ways to resolve that.  Most of them will be a take off on bit vector approach.  You can create a Boolean array and initialize it to `false`.  Whenever a number is printed, you can change the element in the Boolean array for that index to `true`.  If an element is selected, you can check in the Boolean array if it has already been printed.  If yes, you can regenerate the random number, or move to the next unprinted element, making sure that the corresponding Boolean entry is changed to `true` when you print that element.

Answer (score 2):

Your random function gives the repetition, e.g. your dice throw '3' two time out of 4 throws.

What you could do to make it simple, create an array [0..9],
and let the random function swap a[i] with a[j].

Then you get a random permutation. Take the first 5 elements of the permutated array.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    char arr[10][10]={"abc","def","ghi","klm","nop","qrs","tuv","wxy","zab","cde"};
    int found[10] = { 0 };
    int i = 0,j = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        j = rand() % 10;
        while(1){               
            if(!found[j]) break;
            j = rand() % 10;
        }
        found[j] = 1;
        printf("%s\n", arr[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem? It looks as what the OP posted, except you added a missing header.